# How to show sidebar after successful ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using ajax to show data on the sidebar. I can show the sidebar with a button but I m trying to show it after new data is loaded successfully instead of clicking the button again. This is my function to get data which works fine

```
    function showAirportInfo(id) {
        var id = id;
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('front.getairportdetail')}}",
            data: {
                'id': id,
                '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                var dd = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#airportdetail').html(dd);

            }
        });
    };
```

This is my toggle button

```
    <a id="sidebarNavToggler" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" href="javascript:;" role="button"
   aria-controls="sidebarContent" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-unfold-event="click" data-unfold-hide-on-scroll="false" data-unfold-target="#sidebarContent" data-unfold-type="css-animation" data-unfold-animation-in="fadeInRight" data-unfold-animation-out="fadeOutRight" data-unfold-duration="500"> Show Airport </a>
```

This is my sidebar

```
    <aside id="sidebarContent" class="u-sidebar" aria-labelledby="sidebarNavToggler">
  <div class="u-sidebar__scroller">
    <div class="u-sidebar__container">
      <div class="u-header-sidebar__footer-offset">
        <div class="js-scrollbar u-sidebar__body">
          <div class="u-sidebar__content u-header-sidebar__content" id="airportdetail">
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

How can I open the sidebar after successful ajaxcall ? Thanks for your help

Comment: How is the sidebar hidden initially? Something like `$('#sidebarContent').show()` in your `success` handler might work. What have you tried and where do you get stuck?

Comment: Does your words mean that the toggle button works? If you click on the toggle button, does the sidebar appear?

Comment: Try : `$("#sidebarNavToggler").trigger("click")`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which sidebar library did you use.

But, all sidebar libraries support a method to toggle the visibility.
As they mentioned in https://jillix.github.io/jQuery-sidebar/, you can trigger sidebar to open or close at any time.

```
// Sidebar on left (default)
    $(".sidebar.left").sidebar().trigger("sidebar:open");
```

You can add this snippet in success callback method of $.ajax(), something like this

```
function showAirportInfo(id) {
        var id = id;
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('front.getairportdetail')}}",
            data: {
                'id': id,
                '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                var dd = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#airportdetail').html(dd);

                $(".sidebar.left").sidebar().trigger("sidebar:open"); // Here!!!!!
            }
        });
    };
```

If the problem isn't solved yet, please let me know what sidebar library did you use.

Comment: thanks for your time.. I m using a kit from https://htmlstream.com/ and they have a component called unfold.   $("#sidebarNavToggler").trigger("click") this solution From Swati helped but it works like toggle. i need it to be opened only

Comment: Oh yeah, I've just found the documentation of the kit. 
Try  $('#headerSidebarList #headerSidebarHomeCollapse').collapse('show');